# Check if a WooCommerce Order Item has a specific meta data key

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How can I check if my order item has a specific meta data key when getting the order item values using `$order-> get_items()`

Currently to get an order item value I would do this:

```
$product_name = $item_data['name'];
```

I have a meta key called `Address Line 1` however this is only present on some order items. I need to check if an order item has this key present. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use isset():

```
if ( isset( $item_data['name'] ) ) {
    // your code 
}
```